# MPRemoteCommandCenter error: the track is played simultaneously several times

Tags: ios, swift

I have `TableViewController` and `AudioPlayerViewController`. I have a problem with using `MPRemoteCommandCenter`. For example: In `TableViewController` I click on cell and go to`AudioPlayerViewController` next I lock device and control my music with `MPRemoteCommandCenter` - all works fine. But if I further unlock device return to `TableViewController` go again to `AudioPlayerViewController` lock device and press play/pause button my music will play two times at the same time. If I will repeat the action my music will play three times at the same time. And etc... How to fix it?

code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate {
    
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
    let musicOperation = OperationQueue()
    var timer: Timer?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var timeElapsed: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var timeDuration: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var logo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var volumeView: UIView!
    
    var index = 0
    var buttonIndex = 0
    
    var endOfChapterSleepTimer = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Table View Index
        buttonIndex = masterIndex
        
        musicOperation.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(index, forKey: "index")
        
        if index > 0 {

            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
            
            if let documentDirectoryURL: NSURL = urls.first as NSURL? {
                
                let soundURL = documentDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("/\(masterIndex)/\(index).mp3")
                
                UserDefaults.standard.set(index, forKey: "\(masterIndex)")
                
                do {
                    
                    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL!)
                    audioPlayer.delegate = self
                    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    play(sender:AnyObject.self as AnyObject)
                    restorePlayerCurrentTime()
                    
                    setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()
                    lockScreen()
                    
                } catch {
                    
                }
            }
            
        } else {
            
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "\(masterIndex)0", withExtension: "m4a")!
            
            do {
                
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
                audioPlayer.delegate = self
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                play(sender:AnyObject.self as AnyObject)
                
                setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()
                lockScreen()
                
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    // MARK: - Audio player controller
    
    @IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
        if !audioPlayer.isPlaying{
            audioPlayer.play()
            slider.maximumValue = Float(audioPlayer.duration)
            timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .commonModes)
            restorePlayerCurrentTime()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        } else {
            audioPlayer.pause()
            playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func fastForward(sender: AnyObject) {
        var time: TimeInterval = audioPlayer.currentTime
        time += 15.0 // Go Forward by 15 Seconds
        if time > audioPlayer.duration {
            audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(audioPlayer, successfully: true)
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = time
            updateTime()
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func fastBackward(sender: AnyObject) {
        var time: TimeInterval = audioPlayer.currentTime
        time -= 15.0 // Go Back by 15 Seconds
        if time < 0 {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = 0
            updateTime()
        } else {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = time
            updateTime()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Audio player time
    
    private func restorePlayerCurrentTime() {
        let currentTimeFromUserDefaults : Double? = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentTime\(masterIndex)\(index)") as! Double?
        if let currentTimeFromUserDefaultsValue = currentTimeFromUserDefaults {
            audioPlayer.currentTime = currentTimeFromUserDefaultsValue
            slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func updateTime() {
        let currentTime = Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        let minutes = currentTime/60
        let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60
        
        let durationTime = Int(audioPlayer.duration) - Int(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        let minutes1 = durationTime/60
        let seconds1 = durationTime - minutes1 * 60
        
        timeElapsed.text = NSString(format: "%02d:%02d", minutes,seconds) as String
        timeDuration.text = NSString(format: "-%02d:%02d", minutes1,seconds1) as String
        
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "currentTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(durationTime, forKey: "durationTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        
        slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
    }
    
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        
        playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        
        let currentTime = 0
        let durationTime = 0.1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentTime, forKey: "currentTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(durationTime, forKey: "durationTime\(masterIndex)\(index)")
        slider.value = Float.init(audioPlayer.currentTime)
        timer?.invalidate()
        
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/\(masterIndex)/\(index+1).mp3"))
        
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){
            
        
        index = index + 1
        viewDidLoad()
            
        } else {
            
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Audio player lock screen
    
    func lockScreen() {
        
        var albumArtwork : MPMediaItemArtwork!
        let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "infoImage")!
        
        albumArtwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
            return image
        })
        
        let infotitle = "title"
        
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist : "",
            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle : infotitle,
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork : albumArtwork,
            MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle : "",
            MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime : Int(audioPlayer.currentTime),
            MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: Int(audioPlayer.duration)]
        
    }
    
    func setupMediaPlayerNotificationView()  {
        
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.audioPlayer.play()
            self.lockScreen()
            self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            print("play")
            return .success
        }
        
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.audioPlayer.pause()
            self.lockScreen()
            self.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            print("pause")
            return .success
        }
        
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [15]
        commandCenter.skipBackwardCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.fastBackward(sender: self)
            self.lockScreen()
            print("fastBackward")
            return .success
        }
        
        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.preferredIntervals = [15]
        commandCenter.skipForwardCommand.addTarget { event in
            self.fastForward(sender: self)
            self.lockScreen()
            print("fastForward")
            return .success
        }
        
        commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changedThumbSlider(_:)))
        
    @objc func changedThumbSlider(_ event: MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        let time = event.positionTime
        audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(time)
        self.lockScreen()
        return .success
    }
    
    // MARK: - Audio player slider
    
    @IBAction func slide(_ slider: UISlider) {
        musicOperation.cancelAllOperations()
        let operation = BlockOperation()
        audioPlayer.currentTime = TimeInterval(slider.value)
        self.lockScreen()
        musicOperation.addOperation(operation)
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        audioPlayer.pause()
        timer?.invalidate()
        musicOperation.cancelAllOperations()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
        
        // Navigation Bar
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 55/255, green: 60/255, blue: 65/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whats happening is that everytime you goto AudioPlayerViewController you  enable MPRemoteCommandCenter, however when you go back to TableViewController you are not calling removeTarget. this is your issue.

calling something like the below in viewWillDisappear to removeTarget

```
func setupMediaPlayerNotificationView(_ enable: Bool)  {

let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

if enable {
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenPlay(_:)))
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenPlay(_:)))
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenNextTrack(_:)))
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenPreviousTrack(_:)))
} else {
    commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenPlay(_:)))
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenPlay(_:)))
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenNextTrack(_:)))
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(self.lockScreenPreviousTrack(_:)))
    }
}
```

example to follow up question:

```
@objc func lockScreenPlay(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
    self.playButton(AnyObject.self)
    return .success
}

@objc func lockScreenNextTrack(_ event: MPRemoteCommandEvent) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        self.playerDidFinishPlaying()
    return .success
}
```

Comment: I create `@objc func lockScreenPlay() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus` and other functions but in `setupMediaPlayerNotificationView ` have errors `Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'lockScreenPlay'`